# How do I get my .NET development server to use an unusual font?

Tags: .net, fonts, development-environment, asp.net-development-serv, localserver

I'm working on a print template for a postal mailer.

We are using the USPSIMBStandard font to create the barcode and I'm trying to test it locally.

When I debug the project locally and view the mailer (as HTML, we use an HTML-PDF converter to turn the web page into a nicely-printing PDF) I simply see the text I put in, instead of seeing the text displayed in the barcode font.

I have the font installed on my local machine, of course, but I don't think it's being used by Visual Studio's local development server.  I'm sure the font is 'supposed' to be used, as I can inspect the relevant HTML element, and I see the CSS font declaration (though the font name is grayed out, not dark like Arial or Times New Roman would be).

What steps do I need to take to ensure that the correct font is used?

Comment: You need to show some code...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: my question isn't around code.  I have determined that the font is being correctly referenced.  The font simply isn't found, and I haven't been able to find any references online to adding it to .NET's development server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was going wrong - the .NET Development Server **was** using my font correctly.

The selection rules I had were at the top of Firebug, but were being overridden somehow (without Firebug showing them as crossed out).

Adding an '!important' to the rule, an act of last resort in CSS, seems to have fixed it.  My barcode is a barcode now.